# External .ttf font in a React Native app for Android?

Tags: react-native

I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@gattermeier/custom-fonts-in-react-native-for-android-b8a331a7d2a7#.aw559w53u

My font is located here: android/app/src/main/assets/fonts

And it's lowercase: 04b03.ttf

But it doesn't work, why ?

SOLVED:

I followed this tutorial too: https://blog.bam.tech/developper-news/add-a-custom-font-to-your-react-native-app

Then I deleted and then I rebuild the app